# web calling function using mvvm pattern in swift

Tags: ios, swift, web, mvvm

I’m trying to implement MVVM design pattern using swift but few things are not clear to me which are mentioned below.

I need to get list of flowers and display it tableview.
I will call web api which will give details of different types of Flower. 
So I created Class Flower (as Model) and FlowerViewModel class as (ViewModel) and ViewController had the tableview in it.

But not sure, in which class should I place the calling of web api and parsing JSON response ?
As of now I have both these placed in the FlowerViewModel class

Please suggest if need to do correction for placing of these two functions or my assumption is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `Web Service API` class should be **separate** following **Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)** but the caller or the instance of this class should be in view model. **ViewModel** delegates the service to call the `Web API` and from the **parsed** response, it takes the list of flowers binding these items to the `UITableView`. That is how I am implementing in `MVVM`.

Making it clear:

```
class FlowerFetcher {
    func getFlowers(callback: ([Flowers])->()) {}
}

class FlowerViewModel {
    private var flowerService: FlowerFetcher?

    init(flowerService: FlowerFetcher?) {}
}
```